# Problem getting user input from the console

Tags: python-3.x

I am probably overlooking something very simple here but for some reason when i run this block of code, it will only ask for the menu_selection var, it will not ask for input from any of the if cases

```
import user

print("1.) Login")
print("2.) Register")
print("3.) Exit")

menu_selection = input("Selection:")

if menu_selection == 1:
    username = input("Enter username:")
    password = input("Enter password:")
    login_user = username, password

elif menu_selection == 2:
    username = input("Enter username:")
    password = input("Enter password:")
    new_user = user.User(username, password)

elif menu_selection == 3:
    exit("PyMess closed.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the result stored in `menu_selection` will be a [`string`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)) - as that is the return type of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). Make it an [`int`](http://Integer).

```
menu_selection = int(input("Selection:"))
```

Note that this will fail if you enter a non-integer value when you run the program.